# animatedgraphics and multiple files per frame

Tags: pdftex, animate

I can make an animated pdf using `\animatedgraphics`. But I have 4 plot series, 10 each, that I want them to be animated alongside each other.

This means the desired output will have a 10 frame animated graphics, each including 4 plots in a 2x2 grid.

From the [manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex2e/contrib/animate/animate.pdf) it seems `\animateinline` must do the job, but I can't figure out how.

Here is what I've tried:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}{2}
  \multiframe{9}{ia=1+1, ib=2+2}{
    \strut
    \noindent\null\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{a\ib} \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{b\ib} \hfill\null

    \noindent\null\hfill\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{c\ia} \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{d\ia} \hfill\null
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal working example showing what you've tried: 'I can't figure out how' doesn't really give us much to go on.

Comment: The output of what I put in the question, has them in 1x4 format, not a 2x2 grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to obtain the output I wanted this way:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}{2}
  \multiframe{9}{ia=1+1, ib=2+2}{
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{a\ib} &
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{b\ib} \\

    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{c\ia}  &
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{d\ia} \\
\end{tabular}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
```